# How to find matrix elements that satisfy a condition - and store them in another array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix (with name `'im'`) as shown below:

[image]

The matrix only contains `NaNs` and characters `‘A+’, ‘A-‘, ‘B+’ and ‘B-‘`, but can have as many rows as possible.
I need to find **(row-wise)** any `jPositions` at which I have at least any one of `‘A+’ and ‘B+’`, or `‘A+‘ and ‘B-‘`, or `‘A-‘, and ‘B-‘`, or `'A-' and 'B+'`. I will as well want to store these positions in another `matrix P` as shown below.

[image]

`Matrix P` has `no. of rows = k` but k is unknown from the onset. Note that 2, 3, and 4 shown in `matrix P` represents the `jPositions` from `'im'` that satisfies the condition of interest.

I have this pseudocode below (not sure if it is right though), but I am struggling to figure out how to code this.

`For I = 1: size(im, 2)
   If any of q, r, s, t, u has at least one of ‘A+’ or ‘A-‘, and any of q, r, s, t, u has at least one of ‘B+’ or ‘B-‘,
    Then: 
    -select that position.
    -Store the result in matrix P
    end
end`

Please any help, suggestions or advice on this is very much appreciated? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the data type of your table? Is it a `table`? Cell array? The solutions for this problem heavily depend on the data type.

Comment: It is a cell array

Comment: Does the cell array contain the header information, or does it just contain the grades + `NaN`?

Comment: Oh no! it doesn't contain the header information, neither does it contain the first column `('jPositions')`.

Comment: OK, could you clarify how you obtained the `count` column of the resulting matrix `P`? I can't quite understand it from your description.

Comment: The `count` column in `matrix P` is the number of rows (capturing row positions) that satisfy the conditions of interest from `'im'`. `matrix P` should ideally be a kx1 matrix because no need for the `count` column as well as the header information. I hope this clear?

Comment: `count` is just the no. of `jPositions` that satisfy the conditions of interest. It is irrelevant, hence `matrix P` should be a kx1 matrix instead. Maybe this explanation could be better?

Comment: What version of Matlab?  2016b has some nice string operations that would be fun to try on this.

Comment: @Matt, thank you for your response. it is 2015a, but i could get access to 2016b if needed.

Comment: @User1772 So is this a 2D cell array with each element being an individual cell? For example, would the matrix look something like this? `matrix = {NaN, 'A+'; 'B-', NaN};`?

Comment: @rayryeng i am not sure if you are referring to `im` or `matrix P`. Could you please clarify? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a more elegant solution, but this should work:

having your matrix:

```
im = {NaN NaN 'B-' NaN NaN; 'A-' NaN NaN 'B+' NaN; NaN 'A+' 'B+' NaN 'B-'; NaN NaN NaN 'B-' 'A+'};
```

You can find your position using:

```
jPositions = find( ( any(strcmp('A+', im),2) | any(strcmp('A-', im),2) ) & ( any(strcmp('B+', im),2) | any(strcmp('B-', im),2)) );
```

strcmp returns a logical matrix. any with 2 as a second argument returns a logical vector which indicates for each row weather it contains the string. These are then combined using logical operators and find returns the indices of the rows which are true.

This returns:

```
jPositions = 2  3  4
```

Comment: Thank you @Aerl. I would check your code pretty soon. Please, what is the `M` in the 2nd line of your code? position 2 is valid, only that i mistakenly didn't include it in the question. Please see the edited version. Cheers!

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to change it in the second line M is your im.
This version would also accept cases with 'A+' and 'A-' in a row. If you want to exclude it you can use xor as a logical operator.
I updated the command to find all four combinations.

Comment: Thank you so much @Aerl. Works perfectly. Please, i like to make one more request. How can I also find the number of times each sets of `'A+' and 'A-'` as well as `'B+' and 'B-'` occurs for each row? For instance in in the matrix `im`, we have `row 1: A=0; B=1; row 2: A=1; B=1; row 3: A=1; B=2; row 4: A=1; B=1; row n: A=?; B=?` Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can do a sum on the logical array: `numel_A = sum(strcmp('A+', im),2) + sum(strcmp('A-', im),2);` And then the same for B: `numel_B = sum(strcmp('B+', im),2) + sum(strcmp('B-', im),2);`

Comment: thanks @Aerl. works perfectly. I tried to adapt this so as to solve another issue but it seems i haven't got it correctly. Please see my recent question. Many thanks.